# Android JNI call Java method from native thread

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a method in my java class from within a thread in the native code but not having any success. These are the global vars:

```
JavaVM* javaVM = NULL;
jclass activityClass;
jobject activityObj;
```

Code called on initialisation of the native code:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
naInit(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pObj, jstring pFileName, jstring, defaultStorageDirectory) {
  pEnv->GetJavaVM(&javaVM);
  jclass cls = pEnv->GetObjectClass(pObj);
  activityClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>((jclass) pEnv->NewGlobalRef(cls));
  activityObj = pEnv->NewGlobalRef(pObj);
}
}
```

Code used within the thread function:

```
void *decodeAndRender(void * args) {
  JNIEnv *env;
  javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
  jmethodID retryStartVideoMethodID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "retryStartVideo", "()V");
  env->CallVoidMethod(activityObj, retryStartVideoMethodID);
  javaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
  return 0;
}
```

Java code :

```
public void retryStartVideo() {
    Log.d(TAG, "METHOD CALLED FROM CPP ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
}
```

Error in logcat:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/Class;.retryStartVideo()V"
```

I have set the instances of the calling class to be a global ref and used that when calling from within the thread function but it is still failing to find the method. I can use similar code to call a static method no problem but I need to be able to call a non static one.

Comment: whats the java look like?

Comment: Why are you calling `GetObjectClass` on `activityClass`?

Comment: @TankorSmash I've updated the code to show the Java method.

Comment: @Michael I was under the impression this was the correct approach. What should I be passing in? I've also tried to call GetMethodID(activityClass, "retryStartVideo", "()V") with the same result.

Comment: You're supposed to pass a valid reference to the class that contains the method. `GetObjectClass(activityClass)` gives you a reference to `java.lang.Class`, which presumably doesn't contain `retryStartVideo`. Since you haven't posted a minimal complete example it's hard to say what you might be doing wrong. For example, whether you're correctly attaching the native thread to the JavaVM before attempting to use the JNIEnv.

Comment: @Michael I've updated the question with more of the code now. I'm still trying to debug it as well but if there's anything else you need to demonstrate what might be causing the problem please let me know. The help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the call to `GetObjectClass` it should not longer say `Ljava/lang/Class;` in the error message. So what does it say instead?

Comment: @Michael I've replaced the call with :

activityClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>((jclass) pEnv->NewGlobalRef(pObj));

I presume it was correct to replace the call to GetObjectClass(cls) with pObj?

This is the error I am now getting:

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void bmce.esdac.com.firecam.ui.fragments.rtsp.RTSPFragment.retryStartVideo() on instance of java.lang.Class<bmce.esdac.com.firecam.ui.fragments.rtsp.RTSPFragment>

Comment: Huh? The call I was referring to as incorrect was `env->GetObjectClass(activityClass)`. _"I presume it was correct to replace the call to GetObjectClass(cls) with pObj?"_ There's no `GetObjectClass(cls)` in the code you've posted. In any case, a class and an instance of that class (i.e. an object) are not the same thing.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I pasted the wrong things in. I've updated it as per your suggestion and get the same error with Ljava/lang/Class; - I've updated the question to contain the latest code I am using. This seems wrong to me as presumably it should be finding a reference to my Java class but seems to be finding the generic Class reference somehow.

Comment: Well, maybe you've mistakenly declared `naInit` as static in your Java code or something like that. Without having a comple example with all the C++ and Java code it's difficult to say anything further.

Comment: It was indeed defined as static in the java code. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot for the pointers, it's been a huge help!